# Redirecting to the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm

It is a code that is open since an email that is ended to the user via email, and when they open the link, it guides to the user at the endpoint.

At the end of the function I want to redirect to the user to a new page, but the redirect is not working, why it doesn't work?

```
async getToken(req, res) {
    // const { token } = req.params;
    let { access_token } = req.query;
    access_token = access_token.replace(/\s/g, '');


    let decoded;
    try {
      decoded = jwt.verify(access_token, process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION);
      const email_consulted = decoded.email; // you are returning a success response but you havent finished the process yet. Usually the success is sent on the end of the process
      let select = await pool.query(
        `SELECT User_email FROM user WHERE User_email='${email_consulted}'`
      );

   

    //   console.log(select);

      if (select.length > 0) {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          code: 400,
          message: "Email ya existe"
        });
      }

      const result = await pool.query(
        `INSERT INTO user (User_email) VALUES ('${email_consulted}')`
      );
      let selectid = await pool.query(
        `SELECT ID_user FROM user WHERE User_email='${email_consulted}'`
      );

      const id = selectid[0].ID_user

      const token = jwt.sign(
        { id }, 
         process.env.JWT_ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION,
        {expiresIn: '30d' }
    )
      res.cookie("_$",token);
      res.json({
        sucess: true,
        code: 201,
        message: "Usuario añadido exitosamente",
        token
      });
 
      return window.location.replace("http://seth.com/dashboard.html?ftime=0");
      // if (select != "") {
      //     const result = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO user (User_email) VALUES (${email_consulted})`);
      // }
    } catch (err) {
      return res.json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you using express??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to redirect *on the server*, not on the client.  `window` isn't defined on the server, so this will resut in an error.  Use the `res` object to return your response, just like you already do elsewhere.  In this case the response is a redirect:

```
res.redirect('http://seth.com/dashboard.html?ftime=0');
```

Side note: You don't need to `return res...`, just call the functions on `res` appropriately.  The `res` object itself (and subsequently the framework) is responsible for responding to the client, not you.